# OpenAL32.dll missing error

Tags: c++, dll, openal, lib

I have downloaded gorilla-audio source code to use it in my software, but when I use the external library from OpenAL (in gorilla-audio, the OpenAL32.lib) the project compiles with no errors or anything, but it doesn't run normally, I still haven't implemented anything from gorilla sound, just wanted to check that after adding the library it would still work the same before editing anything, but it just doesn't, I have linked everything and used the correct version of `.lib` but when I run the project it says:

> The program can't start because OpenAL32.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

What should I do, I've googled that but I'm just scared to download random things, plus I don't even know where should I put it.

Any help guys,
Thanks ^_^

Comment: Look like you need one of these: https://openal.org/downloads/

Comment: @RichardCritten it worked, thank you so much <3